# Testing if distribution is geometric and finding is parameter.

Tags: probability-distributions

I was doubting whether this was better suited on a math page or on a programming page but I thought just start with the fundamentals. I'm working on the following: I have constructed a exponential distribution in Matlab via log(rand(1000,1). Now the question asks me to the divide the positive real into segments and divide the found values over these segments.

My question is about the following part, it asks me to show that these segments follow a geometric distribution.

Why should it follow a geometric distribution and how can i prove it? I've tried to construct QQ plots for example but the major problem is i don't know anything on the parameter and I haven't got a clue how to find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: for an exponential random variable, $$P\{na<X\leq (n+1)a\}=\exp(-na\lambda)-\exp(-(n+1)a\lambda)=\left(\exp(-a\lambda)\right)^n(1-\exp(-a\lambda))=(1-p)^np$$ where $p=1-\exp(-a\lambda)$. Does this remind you of anything?

Comment: It's getting to me again I think. So lets say I want to use the geometric distribution to simulate a fair dice is it also through if I work back to find the a for which the chance is 1/6. I find the rate parameter for my exponential distribution lambda and p=1/6 to find a?